# Making an image unclickable/undragable

Tags: html, css, image, right-click

I have an image with text and links over it, and I want to make it so that I can highlight the text as I please without running the risk of dragging the background image instead.

The webpage has a background image already, and this image is a secondary background for the content.

I tried setting it as a background for the bounding box the content is set in, but that does not seem to be possible. If possible I'd like to set the image so that it can neither be clicked on, nor dragged.

I only have experience with html and css.

here is my code
Html:

```
<div id="bounding">

<div id="backgroundimage"><img src="image.png" width="1010" height="739"></div>

<div id="image"><img src="image.jpg" width="300" height="500"></div>

<div id="text2">
<h2><CENTER>Tital</CENTER></h2>

<h5>Text</h5>

<p>text</p>

<h5>text</h5> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bounding {position: relative;hight:739px;width:1010px;border:2px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:auto;z-index:7;margin-top:40px;}

#image {position:absolute;left:635px;top:160px;z-index:2;}

#text2 {position:absolute;z-index:4;left:100px;top:206px;width:513px;height:455px;padding right:22px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;scrollbar-base-color: #666666; scrollbar-arrow-color: #9ACD32;color: #494949;}

#backgroundimage {z-index:1;}
```

Comment: You need to add many layers, try with z-index

Comment: can you provide your codes .both html and css

Comment: `<CENTER>` doesn't exist.

Comment: @j08691 I don't mean to be rude, but the center tag does exist, it's supported by all browsers, and I can see it working on my website...

Comment: You're not rude, just uninformed. The `<center>` tag was deprecated about a decade ago, maybe more, and not valid at all in HTML5. Just because some browsers render it, doesn't mean you should use it. As the [W3 says](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/center), "No, really, don't use it."

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the user-select CSS3 property.

```
img {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;  
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/user-select

Comment: Thanks, It can now not be selected by highlighting, but It can still be clicked, draged, and dropped. So half way there.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the background in the css?

```
#image 
{position:absolute;left:635px;top:160px;z-index:2;background:url(image.jpg);}
```

Comment: Do you mean define the image as a background in css somehow? I tried to set the image as a background for the bounding box once, but it did not seem to work. Though maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: Just let everything as it is, except remove `<img ... />` between `<div id="image"> </div>` and add `width: 300px;  height:300px;  background:url(image.jpg);` to your `#image` css.